# IF Statement <= Date Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to complete this IF statement where IF DATE CREATED is earlier than 31 December, 2017, THAN input CCEA-17-ID#; OTHERWISE input CCEA-18-ID#.

Currently, this code:  =IF([DATE CREATED]<="December 31, 2017",("CCEA-17-"&[Submission ID#]+147)) doesn't get an error, but "CCEA-17-ID# is input regardless of date.

=IF([DATE CREATED]<="December 31, 2017",("CCEA-17-"&[Submission ID#]+147),("CCEA-18-"&[Submission ID#]+147))  IT ERRORS OUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to compare string with a date.  Also, you have a false part missing from your condition. Try this, important thing is `Date` function:

```
=IF([DATE CREATED]<= Date(2017,12,31),("CCEA-17-"&[Submission ID#]+147),("CCEA-18-"&[Submission ID#]+147)
```

Comment: Adding the Date function fixed the problem.  However, it does not work on other days, unless I modify (OK) the Calculated Column, everyday.  This is a short term fix, how do we get a long term fix?

Comment: What do you mean by 'other days'?  If you are trying to do something with Today's date remember calculated column only works when you  add/modify item.

Comment: By other days, I mean a different day other than the one it was created.  Today isn't part of the code, so I didn't think it would effect it.  Is there a different way of getting this accomplished and not have to add/modify the item every day?

Comment: Considering you are on the SharePoint Online you can use MS Flow.  It would be much easier and better.

Comment: I apologize, I'm on SP Server, not online

Comment: You can use SharePoint designer workflow