# Follow-on Question to IF Statement <= Date Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online

Follow-on question to [IF Statement <= Date Calculated Column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234889/if-statement-date-calculated-column):

Adding the Date function fixed the problem. However, it does not work on other days, unless I modify (OK) the Calculated Column, everyday. This is a short term fix, how do we get a long term fix?

It also reverted to "CCEA-18-147", instead of "...-295" after I modified the name of the item.

Comment: Based on your post, your requirement is “Check if Date Created is earlier than 31 December 2017, than input CCEA-17-(ID+147), otherwise input CCEA-18-(ID+147)”. Why do you need to modify the calculated column Every Day? What is the data you need to modify? What do you want to achieve? Could you provide some samples?

Comment: Disregard...the issue has resolved itself

Comment: So, after all, the problem is still there.

Comment: So, after all, the problem is still there.  The item Tracking # comes in as ...-147 on the List and in the workflow e-mails "Please do not reply.  This is an automated email.

***VIEW IN HTML***

480 ISRW/CCEA is processing Tracking #CCEA-18-147."
The Tracking # is offset by 147 due to previous entries.                     If I modify (click OK) to the Tracking # column, the entry updates in the List.  How do I have the Tracking # updating automatically?

Comment: Add "Pause for Duration" before the actions, see if it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your previous post, and to achieve what you want, you can use multiple conditions in you SharePoint [calculated column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx).

```
=IF(
    AND(
        [DATE CREATED] <= Date(2017,12,31),
        [DATE CREATED] <> Date(2017,12,31)
    ),
    ("CCEA-17-"&[Submission ID#]+147), ("CCEA-18-"&[Submission ID#]+147")
)
```